# Docker: Unable to connect one container with another on same network

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've a following `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  # Database
  database:
    image: mongo
    container_name: database
    restart: always
    volumes: ["dbdata:/data/db"]
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=myusername
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
    ports:
      - 7000:27017
    command: mongod
    networks:
      - webapp
  # Server
  server:
    container_name: server
    restart: always
    build: ./server
    volumes: ["./server:/var/www", "/var/www/node_modules"]
    ports:
      - "9000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - webapp
networks:
  webapp:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

Now, I'm able to connect with my mongo database from my local windows machine through mongodb client but my `server` container is not able connect with `database` container.

I'm using following connection URI on my server to establish a connection:

`mongodb://myusername:mypassword@database:7000/mydatabase`

It must be noted that on my local machine I'm using the same URI to connect successfully with the database, the only difference is that I'm using `localhost` instead of `database` (container name) on my local machine.

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Mongo is listening on port 27017. When you connect directly to another container, the port forwarding is unnecessary (and has no effect). Update your database uri to be `mongodb://myusername:mypassword@database:27017/mydatabase`

Comment: @larsks Thanks, that solved the issue.